# send image to the bottom of a td with valign="top" property

Tags: html

I'm having so much problems trying to send an image to the bottom of a td. The problem is that
the td needs to have the `valign="top"` property.

```
<html height="100%">
    <table  height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td height="10%" valign="top" style="background-color: black">  </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td height="80%" valign="top" style="background-color: grey">
            Website content..
            <img  style="position:absolute; right:10px; bottom: 10px " height="45" width="45" src="http://rsm.imap.cc/-images/rss.jpg"></img>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="10%" valign="top" style="background-color: black">  </td>
        </tr>               
    </table>
</html>
```

The most close that I've got is to send the image to the bottom of the website, but this is not what I want to do, the image should remain on the grey background. (the second td)

Comment: Go read up on what the point of reference for absolute positioning is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: put `position: relative;` on the `<td>`, then `position: absolute;` on the `<img>` and give it a `bottom: 0;`.

Then you'll also need to set a `padding-bottom: <height-of-image>px;` on the `<td>` to prevent the image from going over the text.